# Should I split class or keep it all in one?

Tags: c#, classes

Currently, in my project I have one class that is dedicated to the all of the queries for the IBM i and converts it into usable models for my .NET code. There is already 12 methods in this class and there *will* be many, many more to come. This is for a tool that pulls data from our IBM i and pushes it to our internet database server.

Should I split this class up? Should I make it a partial class and put the code across multiple files? Should I do multiple classes?

Just wondering what the best practice is on something like that.

Currently this is the framework I have in place

```
class IbmIDatabase
{
    private DateTime ZERO_DATE = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    private string _connString = String.Empty;
    SystemCodeRepository scr = new SystemCodeRepository();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="IbmIDatabase"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public IbmIDatabase()
    {
    }

    #region System Codes
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all system codes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<SystemCode> GetAllSystemCodes()
    {
    }
    #endregion System Codes

    #region Citations
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all citations.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<ParkingTicket> GetAllCitations()
    {
    }
    #endregion Citations

    #region Queue
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the queued records.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<QueuedRecord> GetQueuedRecords()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Marks the queue as processed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    public void MarkQueueAsProcessed(int id)
    {
    #endregion Queue

    #region Utility Bill Customer
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the utility bill customer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The customer id.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Customer GetUtilityBillCustomer(int id)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the utility bill customer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetUtilityBillCustomer()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Utility Bill Details
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the customer history.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">CustomerId</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<BillHistory> GetCustomerHistory(int id)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the customer history.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<BillHistory> GetCustomerHistory()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Utility Bill Payment Details
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the customer payment history.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<BillPaymentHistory> GetCustomerPaymentHistory(int id)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the customer payment history.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<BillPaymentHistory> GetCustomerPaymentHistory()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Utility Bill Summary
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the customer summary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">CustomerId</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<BillSummary> GetCustomerSummary(int id)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the customer summary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<BillSummary> GetCustomerSummary()
    {
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Within each method can be quite a few lines of code (up to many 100 or so?). I left one of the longest ones so far in the sample code.

Comment: Please post some code (according to the FAQ).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I thought I was within the guidelines since it as a best practice question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This class has a well defined role and by keeping it intact you are satisfying the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). So, I would leave it like that. Perhaps you might want to look into how you could refactor some common code out of each method and into a separate utility class, but that's all.

Comment: Even if I have 40 methods in one file? That just seems like a maintenance nightmare in the long run.

Comment: Why? because of a lot of scrolling up and down? I believe that maintenance gets hampered by spaghetti code, bad/improper dependencies, unclear class roles, state duplication, etc, and not by how many functions you group inside a single file. You should have 100 functions in the class if that is what is required of your class.

Comment: I was just thinking if I use the partial class ability in C#, I could break things apart a bit. Then I would have the files `IbmIDatabase.cs` and `IbmIDatabase.Utilities.cs` and it would be obvious that for utilities related methods, you go in to that file.

Comment: The partial class feature of C# is primarily intended to aid the development of tools like the Visual Studio Forms Designer. But in any case, if you feel it will simplify things for you, fine. I would not do it because when I am looking for something I would rather have one file to scan rather than two. But that's a matter of personal preference. Keep in mind that you can also use the #region directive to group methods within a single file and collapse/expand the groups as you please.

Comment: @MikeWills - break your classes up based on responsibilities, not LOC.  If it takes 40 methods to implement one responsibility, then so be it

Comment: @MikeNakis nails it with this answer. If you are worried about too much scrolling just install addon like Resharper and then you can jump between functions with ALT + \.